# Laravel on Google Cloud Error: (1/1) InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: laravel, gcloud

I have a Laravel application based on the [laravel-auth](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth) Github package running perfectly on my local machine.

But when I deploy it on Google Cloud using this command:

```
gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache
```

it gives me this error in the browser:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path.
```

Here are the relevant contents of my app.yaml file:

```
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
```

I looked up this error on StackOverflow, and I have verified that the following directories / files exist on my Google Cloud deployment:

storage/framework:

- sessions
- views
- cache

I may be missing something simple. Can anyone provide any suggestions on how to solve this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) does not (!?) support a flag `--no-cache`.

Remove it and try the deployment again.

#### Update: `gcloud beta app deploy ... --no-cache`

I was unaware that the flag does exists with [`gcloud beta app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/deploy)

With digging too deeply into unfamiliar territory for me with PHP|Laravel, the issue appears to be related to Laravel not creating the directory paths (even if `/tmp`) is specified. See:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/852#issuecomment-470637632

Comment: Thanks v.much for your comment. It gives same error even when deployed with 'gcloud app deploy' command.

Comment: I think you're headed down the right path in trying to get the Laravel cache configured to use `/tmp`. While I'm very familiar with App Engine, I'm unfamiliar with Laravel and PHP and so am not much help. I noticed that Google's Laravel tutorial used a database rather than file for cache. Database is preferable but, with caveats, file should (!?) work too.

Comment: I think I found the sources you've been using to debug. I was incorrect about `--no-cache` the `gcloud beta app deploy` command includes this flag. (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/deploy). Without digging too deploy into this: could this not be the issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/852#issuecomment-470637632?

Comment: Thanks v.much for your help in this. I tried to set the session and cache to database, but (inspite of setting cache to database) I'm getting a different error now -> (1/1) Exception
The /srv/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried all the solutions in the link you provided. It's just alternating between the two errors I mentioned above. If I can't solve it, I might have to switch over to Amazon AWS (hoping I don't get the same error there as well).

Comment: It's frustrating. Are there any other forums where you may find help? I'm going to call a friend and see whether he can help.

Comment: Assume you've read through and compared your config with this Google tutorial? It's over a year old vote but should work: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks v.much for your help. I had followed the same tutorial which you have linked when I set up the Laravel app. But getting the error even after having followed that tutorial. I have switched over to Amazon AWS, but again it has a learning curve and I'm facing some (different) issues over there. But, Thanks v.much again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although late to the party, this might help others.

What could fix your issue, is to add `mkdir -p ./bootstrap/cache/` to your `composer.json` file.

```
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "mkdir -p ./bootstrap/cache/",
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan nova:publish --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
```

my source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/1167#issuecomment-717571401